# How to use a custom font in SublimeText

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I know a user can change the font_face in preferences with:

```
"font_face": "gohufont-11",
"font_size": 11,
```

But, every-time I try to add a (already installed) non-system font, like *Gohufont* above, it does not work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Install the `TTF` version of the font despite the platform-specific fonts available [from here](http://font.gohu.org/).
2. Install the font, installation is OS specific process (in your case use `Install font` menu entry from windows fonts folder).
3. Copy paste `"font_face": "GohuFont",` to your user preferences file.

Tested it on MacOS and it works with your font, did the same with other fonts on Win 7/8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Use the font name as the value of `font_face`. If the font name is `GohuFont`, use that.

Comment: @Juan Which OS? Where is the font installed? What's the file name?

Comment: Windows 8.1 / Fonts Folder / gohufont-11.fon

Comment: @Juan Ok. The `font_face` value should be `GohuFont`, with a capital F. If it still doesn't work, check if the font is really installed and you can use it from other applications