# CSS font-families in sublime text3, how to link them to internet

Tags: html, css, sublimetext3, font-family

How can I link a font-family from internet (like those in googlefonts: https://fonts.google.com/) to my sublimetext css file?
Notice: it hasn't worked for me by simply linking it to an HTML file which has already been linked to my CSS code.

Comment: See this Q&A --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939302/how-to-use-a-custom-font-in-sublimetext

Answer (score 1):

Put following code into your .css file

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,400i');

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

You have to import the font from Google Fonts into your .css and set the font-family.

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert your font to a web font. There are lot of online converters you can use like this:

https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator