# Sublime text 3 font face

Tags: json, sublimetext3, font-face, preference

Does anyone know how to change the font on sublime text 3? I know that in theory, it is doable change the preference->setting->user editing the json file like that:

```
{
    "font_size": 13,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ]
}
```

Adding the line "font_face": "Menlo", right after the font_size rule. But for some reason, none of my fonts are recognized. Plus I'd like to use or add in some way any google font.

Is it possible?

Comment: But did you have this font installed in your machine? Do you use windows or osx or linux?

Comment: Try put "Verdana", it should work (tried in osx): 
`{
 "font_face": "Verdana",
 "font_size": 10,
 "ignored_packages":
 [
  "Vintage"
 ]
}`

Comment: Verdana works, I run a windows machine

Comment: So do you have `Menio` font installed?

Comment: No, but if I try something like Magneto Bold that I've installed it doesn't work either

Comment: Sublime is sensitive to the face name that you use due to the way the underlying library selects fonts, so the face might not be what you think it is. Not sure offhand how you'd look up the one it's using, though.

Comment: I got it, it was my fault. I was pointing the font folder, not the actual font. Please, publish your answer so I can mark it

Comment: For bold you must use options so:
`{
 "font_face": "Magneto",
 "font_options": ["bold"],
 "font_size": 10,
 "ignored_packages":
 [
  "Vintage"
 ]
}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a custom font in SublimeText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939302/how-to-use-a-custom-font-in-sublimetext)

Comment: Fair enough. And it is doable, in theory, to switch font between languages, like Magneto for javascript and arial for everything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that will work:

```
{
    "font_face": "Menlo",
    "font_size": 13,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ]
}
```

But it's important to remember to use only the font that you have, and not the main folder, if you're in windows, but the specific file (with the specific name inside the font folder)